# Does the vector space of all $3\times3$ matrices include $3\times3$ matrices with $0$ as their determinants?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, determinant

I'm still confused as to how matrices, vector spaces, and subspaces relate to each other. If a vector space $V$ contains all $3\times3$ matrices wouldn't that also mean that matrices whose determinants are $0$ also be included?

Comment: And how would that be problematic?

Comment: If it did not, it wouldn't have a zero element, in contradiction of the definition of a vector space.

Comment: @saulspatz You are referring to the zero matrix (which is always in any subspace) but the OP is asking abut the matrices with determinant equal to zero, those may by or may not in a given subspace.

Comment: @gimusi That's not what he says.

Comment: @saulspatz Ok you have given the example of the zero matrix to show that there is always at least a matrix with $\det=0$?

Comment: Vector space V contains all (3x3) matrices and the set W contains (3x3) matrices with det=0. Is W a subspace of V?

Comment: @gimusi Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @edmonda7 No $W$ is not a subsbace, let consider as counterexample $A$ and $B \in W$, and thus such that $\det A=\det B=0$ but with $A+B=I$ thus $\det(A+B)\neq 0$ and $A+B\not \in W$.

Comment: @edmonda7 Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course the vector space of 3-by-3 (or n-by-n) matrices includes all the matrices and thus also those with determinant equal to zero.

What is *not true* is that the set of all matrices with determinant equal to zero is a subspace, can you see why?

Comment: would this mean that only some matrices with determinant equal to zero fall under the vector space while others, if tested by the axioms of closure, would not work?

Comment: @edmonda7 The set of *all* the n-by-n matrices is a vector space (it is trival to check it by definition).

Comment: @edmonda7 But the set of *all* the n-by-n matrices with $\det=0$ **is not** a vector space. Can you find a counterexample?

Comment: @edmonda7 Maybe the set of 3-by-3 matrices was given with some particular propetries? Could you check your notes again?

Answer (score 0):

The space of $3×3$ matrices over a field $\mathbb F$ is just $\mathbb F^9$.  This includes all the matrices with determinant zero...  The reason is that we get all matrices period, including of any given determinant.  That is the same as all $9$-tuples of elements of $\mathbb F$.  For, there are $9$ entries in a $3×3$ matrix;  and each entry can be any element of $\mathbb F$...

Comment: I can see this confusing the OP as it doesn't explicitly explain why the space of $3\times 3$ matrices over a field $\mathbb{F}$ contains all the matrices with determinant zero. You've just stated that we get $\mathbb{F}^9$ and that it does contain them. But why?

Comment: @DanielBuck Right...  I added a little more.